# Command runs fine from command line but not batch scheduler

Tags: bash, batch-processing, scheduler, sungridengine

Very frustrated.

My script runs fine from the command line. However, when running in the SGE batch scheduler, it does not.

Specifically -- it cannot run a certain command. I get the error: "command not found" and then a printout of my PATH. The program that responds to this command is installed and executable and in my PATH.

1. the PATH is correct
2. The script sources my bash profile which has my PATH
3. If I run the script myself it works!
4. If I type the specific command into the command line it works!
5. The only error comes when run in the scheduler

What could possibly be happening when the scheduler runs this script? Why can't it find the command even though it is in the PATH?

Thanks!

Comment: Which shell is using the scheduler to run the script? is it mangling the PATH after you set it?

Comment: Modify your script to use the full path to the command so it avoids searching in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake: I was accidentally using a script with commands for the PBS scheduler instead of Sun Grid Engine. For some reason it recognized everything except my command to source my PATH.